# Unable to install Ggplot2 package on rstudio.Installed latest Rstudio version not running .dll error,updated win 7 and visual c++ still not launching

Tags: c++, r, ggplot2, rstudio, data-visualization

I had an older version of Rstudio(1.1.463)
was not being able to install ggplot2 package showed an error

> - error in loadnamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libpaths()), versioncheck = vi[[i]]) : namespace 'rlang' 0.4.5 is being loaded, but >= 0.4.10 is required

tried installing rlang again and then gglpot 2 but showed the same error

Then I updated the Rstudio to the latest version (1.4.1717)
It showed an error while launching

> -api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll missing

Downloaded .dll file in the system

Showed new error ucrtbase.abort

> - the procedure entry point ucrtbase.abort could not be located in the dynamic link library api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll

Updated my windows 7 and
Installed visual c++ redistributable for visual studio 2015

Still showing same error

> - the procedure entry point ucrtbase.abort could not be located in the dynamic link library api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll

System - 3GB RAM
Windows 7 home basic
Core i3

I want to learn ggplot function for my job interviews but am not able to install tried on an older version of r studio which showed rlang error and the new version is not launching.
Please help.

Comment: That looks annoying, I wish I could figure it out. You can always try out ggplot2 or anything else in R by setting up a free account at `https://login.rstudio.cloud/` and use it in the web without installing anything locally.

Comment: The latest RStudio requires Windows 10. It's unlikely you'll get things to work on Windows 7. You'd have to use an older version around 1.1 or so. The ggplot2 error you were getting had nothing to to with your RStudio version. It just meant you were trying to update a package that was currently loaded. That means you just needed to restart R before installing.